# Delete all lines beginning with a # from a file

Tags: bash, sed

All of the lines with comments in a file begin with `#`. How can I delete all of the lines (and only those lines) which begin with `#`? Other lines containing `#`, but not at the beginning of the line should be ignored.

Comment: Does it have to work with the common convention that `#blah \<nl>blah` counts as a single "logical line" because the backslash escapes the newline?

Comment: @sarnold: apart from `make`, which utilities use the 'backslash splices lines before ending a comment'?  The shells (bash and ksh tested) don't.  C and C++ do handle newline splicing before other processing of preprocessor directives, but they're directives rather than comments.

Comment: @Jonathan: Awesome. I had assumed that the common `\<nl>` escaping would also work on comments. But wow I was wrong. I haven't been able to find another example yet... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 444, accepted):

This can be done with a [sed one-liner](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30):

```
sed '/^#/d'
```

This says, "find all lines that start with # and delete them, leaving everything else."

Comment: shorter version: `sed /^#/d`

Comment: For linux noobs like me: `sed '/^#/ d' < inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt`

Comment: How can i keep the lines which start with # and delete every other lines i need to remove every contents except which start with #

Comment: Shortest version: `sed -i '/^#/d' filepath`.

Comment: And `sed -i '' '/^#/d' filepath` on Mac ([because the -i suffix is mandatory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16746032/125246))

Comment: What if I need to replace only the first line starting with a string?

Comment: @Viesturs Try this:  ``awk '/^#/ && !first { first=1 ; next } { print $0}' ``

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan better make sure `inputFile.txt` is NOT the same as `outputFile.txt`

Comment: To apply this to all files matching a shell pattern, use something like this (replace *.txt as needed): `for e in *.txt ; do sed -i '/^#/d' $e ; done`

Comment: and how do I specify a file?

Comment: @lesderid, wow, dangerous!  Maybe warn us first?  XD

Comment: Why won't `sed '@^#@d'` work? It only accepts slash.

Answer (score 77):

I'm a little surprised nobody has suggested the most obvious solution:

```
grep -v '^#' filename
```

This solves the problem as stated.

But note that a common convention is for everything from a `#` to the end of a line to be treated as a comment:

```
sed 's/#.*$//' filename
```

though that treats, for example, a `#` character within a string literal as the beginning of a comment (which may or may not be relevant for your case) (and it leaves empty lines).

A line starting with arbitrary whitespace followed by `#` might also be treated as a comment:

```
grep -v '^ *#' filename
```

if whitespace is only spaces, or

```
grep -v '^[  ]#' filename
```

where the two spaces are actually a space followed by a literal tab character (type "control-v tab").

For all these commands, omit the `filename` argument to read from standard input (e.g., as part of a pipe).

Comment: I have added a [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19671392/832230) which builds upon this answer.

Comment: I had troubles using grep in this way on Windows. The solution is to replace ' by ", e.g. `grep -v "^#" filename`

Answer (score 22):

The opposite of Raymond's solution:

```
sed -n '/^#/!p'
```

"don't print anything, except for lines that DON'T start with #"

Comment: ok and what's the advantage here?

Comment: @lacostenycoder It's about the same as any other option presented here, which is enough merit to mention it.

Answer (score 14):

you can directly edit your file with

```
sed -i '/^#/ d'
```

If you want also delete comment lines that start with some whitespace use

```
sed -i '/^\s*#/ d'
```

Usually, you want to keep the first line of your script, if it is a sha-bang, so `sed` should not delete lines starting with `#!`. also it should delete lines, that just contain only a hash but no text. put it all together:

```
sed -i '/^\s*\(#[^!].*\|#$\)/d'
```

To be conform with all sed variants you need to add a backup extension to the `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak '/^\s*#/ d' $file
rm -Rf $file.bak
```

Comment: plus 1 for the one which space

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following for an awk solution -

```
awk '/^#/ {sub(/#.*/,"");getline;}1' inputfile
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer builds upon the earlier [answer by Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8207172/832230).

`grep -Ev "^[[:blank:]]*#"` should filter out comment lines.

`grep -Ev "^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)"` should filter out both comments and empty lines, as is frequently useful.

For information about `[:blank:]` and other character classes, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes.

Comment: Assuming your `egrep` supports that syntax; older versions might not.

Answer (score 3):

You also might want to remove empty lines as well

```sh
sed -E '/(^$|^#)/d' inputfile
```

Comment: Or `grep -v '^ *\(#.*\|\)$' to remove line containing only spaces or spaces before comments too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete from the file starting with a specific word, then do this:

```
grep -v '^pattern' currentFileName > newFileName && mv newFileName currentFileName
```

So we have removed all the lines starting with a pattern, writing the content into a new file, and then copy the content back into the source/current file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all empty lines and also all lines starting with a `#` after any spaces:

```
sed -E '/^$|^\s*#/d' inputfile
```

For example, see the following 3 deleted lines (**including just line numbers!**):

```
1. # first comment
2.
3.         # second comment
```

After testing the command above, you can use option `-i` to edit the input file in place.

Just this!

Answer (score -3):

Here is it with a loop for all files with some extension:

```
ll -ltr *.filename_extension > list.lst

for i in $(cat list.lst | awk '{ print $8 }') # validate if it is the 8 column on ls 
do
    echo $i
    sed -i '/^#/d' $i
done
```