# Add numbers to the beginning of every line in a file

Tags: bash, row-number

How can I add numbers to the beginning of every line in a file?

E.g.:

```
This is
the text
from the file.
```

Becomes:

```
000000001 This is
000000002 the text
000000003 from the file.
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

AWK's *printf*, `NR` and `$0` make it easy to have precise and flexible control over the formatting:

```
~ $ awk '{printf("%010d %s\n", NR, $0)}' example.txt
0000000001 This is
0000000002 the text
0000000003 from the file.
```

Comment: Wonderful! I needed this to populate a huge array of static int declarations, so I had something like `public static final int CONSTANTX;` and I wanted something like `public static final int CONSTANTX;=X` where `X` is the number of the line in the source file. I rearranged your answer as `awk '{printf("%s = %d;\n", $0, NR-4)}' Constants.java` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 124):

Don't use cat or any other tool which is not designed to do that. Use the program:

> nl - number lines of files

Example:

```sh
$ nl --number-format=rz --number-width=9 foobar
$ nl -n rz -w 9 foobar # short-hand
```

Because nl is made for it ;-)

Comment: `ls | nl #nl for dummies`

Comment: nl doesn't really help in all scenarios. see below:

$ cat test123
123

sd






$ nl test123
     1  123

     2  sd







$ awk '{print NR,$0}' test123
1 123
2
3 sd

Comment: It doesn't output the lines until EOF is read. So you can't use it to number output of a long-running program on-line.

Comment: @egorulz Use `-ba` switch.

Answer (score 32):

You're looking for the `nl(1)` command:

```
$ nl -nrz -w9  /etc/passwd
000000001   root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
000000002   daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
000000003   bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
...
```

`-w9` asks for numbers nine digits long; `-nrz` asks for the numbers to be formatted right-justified with zero padding.

Comment: That's the exact answer and a good one, but for a homework style question it may have been better to offer a hint, a link, or a more general purpose solution.

Comment: @Raymond, true enough, but I've not seen any indication that this is homework. Simple? Sure. But there's a giant pile of text-processing utilities on these things that even experienced developers never learn about.

Comment: @Raymond: I suggest undeleting your answer, I like it. Different tools might excel for different reasons, and `awk(1)` certainly excels at tasks like this.

Comment: I only knew because I fell for the a previous question a few minutes ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206280/delete-all-lines-beginning-with-a-from-a-file  Also, the unusual number of leading zeros in the example was another hint :-)

Comment: This is not for homework. I just thought, it could take me 2 hours to figure out how to do that in `awk`, using some for loop, which would take another 30 minutes for the script to run through the file; or I could ask here. I've never heard of `nl` before. Am I posting the wrong kind of questions?

Comment: Village: not at all -- Stack Overflow is intended to answer questions of all levels. @Raymond just noticed that you've got three questions asked in a short time frame asking for solutions to problems similar to homework a professor might assign in a "Learning Unix" course. One alone sounds like someone looking for a solution to a problem, but all three taken together makes us wonder if we're doing your homework for you. :)

Answer (score 17):

`cat -n thefile` will do the job, albeit with the numbers in a slightly different format.

Answer (score 8):

Easiest, simplest option is

```
awk '{print NR,$0}' file
```

See comment above on why nl isn't really the best option.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a bash script that will do this also:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
filename=$1
while read -r line
do
  printf "%010d %s" $counter $line
  let counter=$counter+1
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -pe 'printf "%09u ", $.' -- example.txt
```