# How do I get a SQL row_number equivalent for a Spark RDD?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, row-number, rdd

I need to generate a full list of row_numbers for a data table with many columns.

In SQL, this would look like this:

```
select
   key_value,
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
   row_number() over (partition by key_value order by col1, col2 desc, col3)
from
   temp
;
```

Now, let's say in Spark I have an RDD of the form (K, V), where V=(col1, col2, col3), so my entries are like

```
(key1, (1,2,3))
(key1, (1,4,7))
(key1, (2,2,3))
(key2, (5,5,5))
(key2, (5,5,9))
(key2, (7,5,5))
etc.
```

I want to order these using commands like sortBy(), sortWith(), sortByKey(), zipWithIndex, etc. and have a new RDD with the correct row_number

```
(key1, (1,2,3), 2)
(key1, (1,4,7), 1)
(key1, (2,2,3), 3)
(key2, (5,5,5), 1)
(key2, (5,5,9), 2)
(key2, (7,5,5), 3)
etc.
```

(I don't care about the parentheses, so the form can also be (K, (col1,col2,col3,rownum)) instead)

How do I do this?

Here's my first attempt:

```
val sample_data = Seq(((3,4),5,5,5),((3,4),5,5,9),((3,4),7,5,5),((1,2),1,2,3),((1,2),1,4,7),((1,2),2,2,3))

val temp1 = sc.parallelize(sample_data)

temp1.collect().foreach(println)

// ((3,4),5,5,5)
// ((3,4),5,5,9)
// ((3,4),7,5,5)
// ((1,2),1,2,3)
// ((1,2),1,4,7)
// ((1,2),2,2,3)

temp1.map(x => (x, 1)).sortByKey().zipWithIndex.collect().foreach(println)

// ((((1,2),1,2,3),1),0)
// ((((1,2),1,4,7),1),1)
// ((((1,2),2,2,3),1),2)
// ((((3,4),5,5,5),1),3)
// ((((3,4),5,5,9),1),4)
// ((((3,4),7,5,5),1),5)

// note that this isn't ordering with a partition on key value K!

val temp2 = temp1.???
```

Also note that the function sortBy cannot be applied directly to an RDD, but one must run collect() first, and then the output isn't an RDD, either, but an array

```
temp1.collect().sortBy(a => a._2 -> -a._3 -> a._4).foreach(println)

// ((1,2),1,4,7)
// ((1,2),1,2,3)
// ((1,2),2,2,3)
// ((3,4),5,5,5)
// ((3,4),5,5,9)
// ((3,4),7,5,5)
```

Here's a little more progress, but still not partitioned:

```
val temp2 = sc.parallelize(temp1.map(a => (a._1,(a._2, a._3, a._4))).collect().sortBy(a => a._2._1 -> -a._2._2 -> a._2._3)).zipWithIndex.map(a => (a._1._1, a._1._2._1, a._1._2._2, a._1._2._3, a._2 + 1))

temp2.collect().foreach(println)

// ((1,2),1,4,7,1)
// ((1,2),1,2,3,2)
// ((1,2),2,2,3,3)
// ((3,4),5,5,5,4)
// ((3,4),5,5,9,5)
// ((3,4),7,5,5,6)
```

Comment: This question is an extension of several other partially answered questions, namely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838614/how-to-sort-an-rdd-in-scala-spark, http://qnalist.com/questions/5086896/spark-sql-how-to-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group, http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201408.mbox/%3CD01B658B.2BF52%25silvio.fiorito@granturing.com%3E, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022059/filter-rdd-based-on-row-number, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677180/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-elements-in-spark-rdd

Comment: I'm also looking to answer this question.  [Hive added analytic functions (including `row_number()`) in 0.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-896), and Spark 1.1 supports HiveQL / Hive 0.12.  So it seems that `sqlContext.hql("select row_number() over(partition by ...` should work, but I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)` functionality was added to Spark 1.4.  This answer uses PySpark/DataFrames.

Create a test DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F

testDF = sc.parallelize(
    (Row(k="key1", v=(1,2,3)),
     Row(k="key1", v=(1,4,7)),
     Row(k="key1", v=(2,2,3)),
     Row(k="key2", v=(5,5,5)),
     Row(k="key2", v=(5,5,9)),
     Row(k="key2", v=(7,5,5))
    )
).toDF()
```

Add the partitioned row number:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

(testDF
 .select("k", "v",
         F.rowNumber()
         .over(Window
               .partitionBy("k")
               .orderBy("k")
              )
         .alias("rowNum")
        )
 .show()
)

+----+-------+------+
|   k|      v|rowNum|
+----+-------+------+
|key1|[1,2,3]|     1|
|key1|[1,4,7]|     2|
|key1|[2,2,3]|     3|
|key2|[5,5,5]|     1|
|key2|[5,5,9]|     2|
|key2|[7,5,5]|     3|
+----+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting problem you're bringing up. I will answer it in Python but I'm sure you will be able to translate seamlessly to Scala.

Here is how I would tackle it:

1- Simplify your data:

```
temp2 = temp1.map(lambda x: (x[0],(x[1],x[2],x[3])))
```

temp2 is now a "real" key-value pair. It looks like that:

```
[
((3, 4), (5, 5, 5)),  
((3, 4), (5, 5, 9)),   
((3, 4), (7, 5, 5)),   
((1, 2), (1, 2, 3)),  
((1, 2), (1, 4, 7)),   
((1, 2), (2, 2, 3))
```

]

2- Then, use the group-by function to reproduce the effect of the PARTITION BY:

```
temp3 = temp2.groupByKey()
```

temp3 is now a RDD with 2 rows:

```
[((1, 2), <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x15e08d0>),  
 ((3, 4), <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x15e0290>)]
```

3- Now, you need to apply a rank function for each value of the RDD. In python, I would use the simple sorted function (the enumerate will create your row_number column):

```
 temp4 = temp3.flatMap(lambda x: tuple([(x[0],(i[1],i[0])) for i in enumerate(sorted(x[1]))])).take(10)
```

Note that to implement your particular order, you would need to feed the right "key" argument (in python, I would just create a lambda function like those:

```
lambda tuple : (tuple[0],-tuple[1],tuple[2])
```

At the end (without the key argument function, it looks like that):

```
[
((1, 2), ((1, 2, 3), 0)), 
((1, 2), ((1, 4, 7), 1)), 
((1, 2), ((2, 2, 3), 2)), 
((3, 4), ((5, 5, 5), 0)), 
((3, 4), ((5, 5, 9), 1)), 
((3, 4), ((7, 5, 5), 2))
```

]

Hope that helps!

Good luck.

Comment: Step 3. is genius!

Answer (score 1):

```
val test = Seq(("key1", (1,2,3)),("key1",(4,5,6)), ("key2", (7,8,9)), ("key2", (0,1,2)))
```

test: Seq[(String, (Int, Int, Int))] = List((key1,(1,2,3)), (key1,(4,5,6)), (key2,(7,8,9)), (key2,(0,1,2)))

```
test.foreach(println)
```

(key1,(1,2,3))

(key1,(4,5,6))

(key2,(7,8,9))

(key2,(0,1,2))

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(test, 2)
```

rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Int, Int))] = ParallelCollectionRDD[41] at parallelize at :26

```
val rdd1 = rdd.groupByKey.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toArray)).map(x => (x._1, x._2.sortBy(x => x._1).zipWithIndex))
```

rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[((Int, Int, Int), Int)])] = MapPartitionsRDD[44] at map at :25

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap{ 
  elem =>
   val key = elem._1
   elem._2.map(row => (key, row._1, row._2))
 }
```

rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Int, Int), Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[45] at flatMap at :25

```
rdd2.collect.foreach(println)
```

(key1,(1,2,3),0)

(key1,(4,5,6),1)

(key2,(0,1,2),0)

(key2,(7,8,9),1)

Answer (score 0):

From spark sql, Read the data files... 
`val df = spark.read.json("s3://s3bukcet/key/activity/year=2018/month=12/date=15/*");`

The above file has fields user_id, pageviews and clicks

Generate the activity Id (row_number) partitioned by user_id and order by clicks

```
val output = df.withColumn("activity_id", functions.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("clicks")).cast(DataTypes.IntegerType));
```