# How to delete // comment lines in all files in current folder and subfolders?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to delete all comments inside all script files in the current folder and sub folders. All comment lines start with //. I want to delete the whole line

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548716/delete-all-comments-in-a-file-using-sed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type f |xargs sed -i '\#^//#d'
```

the find part find **all** files, and the `sed` part removes all lines starting with `//`

You can add `-name` option in `find` to do further filtering. check `man find` to get more useful information.

Your pattern contains slash `/`, so with sed's default `/pattern/d` you have to do some escaping. I used `#` as delimiter to save that kind of works, and made the code easier to read.