# Preparing a git commit message before committing?

Tags: git

Is it possible to prepare a commit message prior to a commit, meaning that I will type my commit message before the actual commit or during the working dir so that I know what I am working on and I know what this branch or commit will be all about. When I say "before" I do not mean just couple secs before I enter the commit on the commandline. I literally mean right after a commit or at the starting of a branch so that the next commit will automatically inherit the message in the queue or what ever that might be called.

Naturally I can put these messages during the commit, to me there is a difference. And I can see the argument of well git is not meant for that as well. I am just curious about it.

I also know I can give my branches more meaningful names but I just want a bit space for such purpose.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but about branch descriptions; check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Git can take the commit message from a file using the `-F` or `--file` flags:

```
git commit -F message.txt
```

You can prepare your message in advance in a text file and use that file when you commit.

If you do this often, it makes sense to create an alias for it, for example:

```
done = commit -F message.txt
```

So that you can simply type `git done` to have it always use your text file.

If you make a mistake and commit too fast without updating the message file, not a problem, you can just do `git commit --amend` and fix the message in the commit.

**UPDATE**

The `-e` flag is useful too, as it lets you edit the message before committing:

```
git commit -eF message.txt
```

Comment: That looks like what I need probably. I am accepting your answer. However if there are more ways to achieve it I am personally ready to hear.

Comment: janos is it possible to create a note txt based on the branch? For instance I would like to be able to "git checkout -b mynewbranch" and then this command creates the branch plus the "mynewbranch.commit" text file? I tried somethign with aliases but not achieving it. Any solutions?

Comment: @yaruncan That's really an entirely different question... But anyway, this alias could be what you're looking for or close enough: `newb = "!f() { git checkout -b $1 $2 && echo hello > $1.commit; }; f"`

Comment: thanks. It was not really an entirely different question because that way I can have my text file to pipe into the commit message with every branch, where I can fill with the details of what the branch will be about. I will try your solution

Comment: @yaruncan I just discovered something new: the `-e` is very useful to edit the message before the commit is performed. I updated my answer with this extra info.

Comment: Great. Is there a way that the file given after -eF will be automatically deleted/ignored by Git? Or should I add a line to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Works fine, but lines starting with # are not ignored.

Comment: Seems like # lines are not ignored, why is that??

Answer (score 17):

If using the `--file` option for `git commit` you can pipe in the message through the standard input by using dash (`-`) instead of a file name.

```
echo "Classy commit message" | git commit --file -
```

Comment: Well thanks but this does not address the question, this is just another way of commiting a message, good to know however it is not a solution in anyway to my question unless you can show me how this can be used to solve my issue.

Comment: Well, the point the message being piped is that the source of said message can be any program. It could be from simply printing the contents of a file to having them be compiled from any imaginable source.

Comment: This will have an undesired effect when the left hand side of the pipe contains multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VIM as Git's core editor, then when you run `git commit`, VIM will be opened and you'll be presented with a buffer containing the commented-out output of the `git status` command.

You can then use the VIM command `:read COMMIT_MSG.txt` which will insert the contents of the file `COMMIT_MSG.txt` (your pre-pared commit message) at the current cursor location.

This is really just an alternative to running `git commit -eF COMMIT_MSG.txt`, but I personally find it easier to remember the VIM command `:read` as opposed to having to remember yet another git command line argument. Personal preference, really.

Comment: It's worth noting that this same approach can be used with just about any `$EDITOR`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get git's vim formatting (excluding the comment lines that usually list the included/excluded changes) by [using this command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268889/vim-force-specific-syntax-via-command-line-argument):

```
vi -c 'set syntax=gitcommit'
```

I made an alias (non-git) and added it to my ~/.bashrc.

```
alias ecm="vi -c 'set syntax=gitcommit'"
```

Re-source your .bashrc to turn it on for your current session.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And then use it.

```
ecm message.txt
```

All this was done with Git Bash on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a template file to your project's git configuration and its content will be used each time you start a new commit. This file might be added to **.gitignore** so that its existence will be only relevant for you while developing. Standing in the root of your project, you could for example do:

```
touch .gitmessage
echo "\n# commit message\n.gitmessage" >> .gitignore
git config commit.template .gitmessage
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Perfect! No alias needed. Review/edit at commit. Supports # comments.  Git still adds changed file list at the end. Works with configured editor.  Follows .gitX special file naming scheme.  And.. you can plan ahead using comments and uncomment/edit the appropriate pieces for the current commit.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answers of [LopSae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20447988/2377961) and [janos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20438380/2377961) to auto remove all lines beginning with a # from the input-textfile with command from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206295/2377961).

Result is this command

```
cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG | sed '/^#/ d' | git commit -F -
```

And to make it shorter I suggest to add an alias.

**EDIT**
Creating an alias for this command was more complex than exspeced.
But after some tries and withs [this tuturial](https://jondavidjohn.com/git-aliases-parameters/) I created an alias what works and supports custom parameters.

```
[alias]
  commitmsg  = "!f() { myarg=${@}; cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG | sed '/^#/ d' | git commit -F - $myarg;  }; f"
```

You can use it e.g. with parameter for modified date like this

```
commitmsg --date "2001-01-02 18:00:00"
```