# Git CLI - Use a text file as commit description

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

Since few weeks, I'm trying to improve my level with the use of Git, and recently, I realized that my commits descriptions we're not enough readable..

To make it look better, I would like to write all of the description into a file, and then, use this file as commit descriptor. However, I don't know bash...

Example :

Desc.txt

```
----
-Add of Login
-Debug Http
----
```

`...; git commit -am read("Desc.txt"); ...

How can I achieve that?

Thank !

Comment: A few more ideas in [Preparing a git commit messaging before committing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20438293/5358968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is built into the Git command. See `-F` from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Example:

```
git commit -a -F Desc.txt
```