# How to list only files in Android ADB ?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I can successfully retrieve the directory name by this command

```
ls -d */
```

But I cant display only files from my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `ls -l | grep ^-`

Here is full list options for `ls` command.

```
Option  Description
-a  Displays all files.
-b  Displays nonprinting characters in octal.
-c  Displays files by file timestamp.
-C  Displays files in a columnar format (default)
-d  Displays only directories.
-f  Interprets each name as a directory, not a file.
-F  Flags filenames.
-g  Displays the long format listing, but exclude the owner name.
-i  Displays the inode for each file.
-l  Displays the long format listing.
-L  Displays the file or directory referenced by a symbolic link.
-m  Displays the names as a comma-separated list.
-n  Displays the long format listing, with GID and UID numbers.
-o  Displays the long format listing, but excludes group name.
-p  Displays directories with /
-q  Displays all nonprinting characters as ?
-r  Displays files in reverse order.
-R  Displays subdirectories as well.
-t  Displays newest files first. (based on timestamp)
-u  Displays files by the file access time.
-x  Displays files as rows across the screen.
-1  Displays each entry on a line.
```

Comment: I think this will show only the directory with long format and with permission. I want to list only files not directory. :)

Comment: I think ^d is use for listing directory. But my question was only display files not directory. Thanks for your answer. ^- will show the all files of the current directory.

Comment: @BselfishedLikeaSuccessfulper try  this `ls -l | grep ^-`

Comment: `ls` in Android only supports `lnsRdZaFi` parameters

Comment: ls -d prints only a dot in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you've `sed` binary in your Android device, then do:

```
ls -l | sed '/^d/ d'
```

It will delete all lines starting with `d` from the output of `ls -l` ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206280/delete-all-lines-beginning-with-a-from-a-file)). Why? Because all directories in the output starts with `d` so remove them and you'll get only the file names.

If you don't have the `sed` in Android, then you can `adb pull` the file into PC (saved output of `ls -l`), and process it with (would work only for Linux PC):

```
cat <YOUR_FILE> | sed '/^d/ d'
```