# Converting from ipython-notebook to .py

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to download an `ipython` notebook file as a .py file.  It's working fairly well, except the `.py` file is interspersed with `"In: []"` at cell boundaries.  I could live with them being there, but I'd rather they weren't.
Any simple fix?

Example output (what I see in the `.py` file):

```
# In[4]:

# Get names of all files
text_files = glob.glob('hw3data/*')
#print text_files


# In[5]:

def file_contents(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Edit: Essentially, I'm wondering if it's possible to make notebook itself not output #In[ ].  Is there a commandline option, or a utility, or some kind of %magic?

Edit: Going by https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5780, it looks like the suggested solution is just to use a custom template.  From minrk:

> It's just a marker that indicates where the cells were. It is by design, but it has no effect on the Python, since it is a comment. If you want to remove them, you can use a custom exporter template that doesn't add these comments.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 That's okay for small files, but if I were working on something large, it would be easy to miss some.  Besides, computers exist to serve us, not the other way around

Comment: Why wouldn't something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206280/delete-all-lines-beginning-with-a-from-a-file) work?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
def rc(in_, out_):

    in_ = open(in_, 'r')
    out_ = open(out_,'w')
    out_.write(in_.readline())

    for line in in_:
        if not line.lstrip().startswith('# In['):
            out_.write(line)

    in_.close()
    out_.close()

rc('~/in_file.py', '~/out_file.py')
```

Comment: This ends up deleting all comments as well, I think.  I'll edit the question to be a bit more clear about what I'd like to do.

Comment: @Phox That'd be easy to remedy. Just change the `startswith` to `'# In['`

Comment: It is, yeah, and I'm looking to see if notebook has any hooks I could use to run something like this when it exports to a .py file.  I'm wondering, though, if notebook can be configured to not put them in at all.  It seems really strange, to me at least, that this is included in the output.

Comment: u might also try putting all the code in one cell in your notebook and putting `%%file name_of_file.py` at the top of the cell.

Comment: That's a start in the right direction, but it still requires I modify the notebook before I export it.  I have a hack I'll throw in another answer, but I'm starting to think that there isn't really an answer that doesn't involve either running a script manually after every export, or changing the notebook like you said.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary hack, I found that removing lines seven through nine of the python export template of `nbconvert` (`ipython/IPython/nbconvert/templates/python.tpl` in `site-packages`) stops the input prompt from being output.  This still isn't ideal, as I'm modifying site packages.

Affected lines:

```
{% block in_prompt %}
# In[{{ cell.prompt_number if cell.prompt_number else ' ' }}]:
{% endblock in_prompt %}
```