# Deleting hash from beginning of line with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like to populate a shell variable with the file contents of the file that follow the # (but leave the file as-is) from beginning of one single-line file

I tried

```
file=$(head -n1 $another_filename | sed 's/^#//')
```

but output is the same. I don't want to delete the whole line, just hash.

Comment: `sed  -i.bak 's/^#//' file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all lines beginning with a # from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206280/delete-all-lines-beginning-with-a-from-a-file)

Comment: Another demonstration of [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: Are you REALLY trying to remove the `#` from the file or are you trying to populate a shell variable with the file contents of the file that follow the `#` but leave the file as-is? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: OK, thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

Found it with your help of course.
`file=$(head -n1 $filename |sed 's/^#//')`

Comment: Absolutely not. Take another look at the comments you received and if you don't see the answer there then clarify your question to explain why not.