# linux merge multiple files, but skip lines starting with '#'

Tags: linux, cat

I have a list of 10 files that I want to merge into one file.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
...
file10.txt
```

I normally do this with cat

```
cat file*.txt > merged_file.txt
```

However, I don't want the lines starting with '#' to be included in the merged_file.txt. How do I do this?

Comment: So just remove lines starting with `#`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8207172/9072753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:
`cat file*.txt | egrep -v '^#.*$' > merged_file.txt`

Comment: You could `egrep ... -h file*.txt`. Also note that `egrep` is deprecated . Use `grep -E`.

Comment: You can omit '.*$' from the `grep` pattern.

Comment: You are right, a simpler form: `cat file*.txt | egrep -v '^#' > merged_file.txt